# How to add a linked brushing feature to my bokeh plots (set in a grid)?

Tags: python, graph, bokeh

I have 2 line graphs created using the bokeh library set in a grid. How do you add a linked brushing feature to multiple plots in this library?

Here is a snippet of the code:

```
graph1 = figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=400, title=None)
graph1.circle('x', 'y0', source=source)

graph2 = figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=400, title=None)
graph2.circle('x', 'y1', source=source)

p = gridplot([[graph1, graph2]])
```

Comment: HoloViews is probably the easiest way to get Bokeh linked brushing' https://holoviews.org/user_guide/Linked_Brushing.html